# Android: Error While Connecting firebase and Google Maps Activity Together

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
package com.example.dhrumit.google_maps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements      OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public FirebaseDatabase database;
public DatabaseReference mRef ;
public Query query;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = database.getReference().child("users");
    query= mRef.orderByChild("phone");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (DataSnapshot postDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Double Latitude = (Double)       postDataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
                Double Longitude = (Double) postDataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue();
                String Name =  (String) postDataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                LatLng Location = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title(Name));
                builder.include(Location);
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,0);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have written above code to create a Google Map Activity to display Map with Markers on it, Location of the markers are fetched from firebase database but **I am Having Runtime Errors as  Shown Below.**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzTt()Z in class        Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.dhrumit.google_maps-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes7.dex)
                                                                                               **at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)**
                                                                                     at com.example.dhrumit.google_maps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:35)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: can you post dependencies you are using.

Comment: `dependencies dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`
**Above Are the dependencies used by me** @Minkoo

Comment: Try to put all of your dependencies at the same level. Your firebase is at level 10.0.1 and gms at level 10.2.0. Make it same.

Comment: they are already at a level which you mentioned @Minkoo

Comment: Try for same play-services and firebase version. It seems to be different in your code.

Comment: Got the problem solved thanks a lot @Minkoo

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the different version of the dependencies of **Firebase database** & **Google Play services**. Make them same or use the following dependencies, the issue will be resolved.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
```